# Constructor Node cannot be applied to given types while working with nodes

Tags: java, linked-list, enqueue

I am working on a code that puts new elements on MyStack if they are unique. I had to copy and paste the node starting code, so I'm having a bit of trouble with an issue. I keep getting two error messages, even after trying various workarounds and I'm not really understanding why. I've even tried using some helper functions I've previously made that have worked before so I'm extra confused.
The two errors I consistently get are:

-cannot infer type arguments for MyStack.Node (actual and formal arguments differ in length)
-constructor node cannot be applied to given types. Required, no arguments, found: anything,

Here's my code:

```
public class MyStack<Anything>
{
     private Node first, last;
     private class Node<Anything> 
     { 
         Anything item; 
         Node next; 
     }
     
     public boolean contains(Anything value)
    {
        for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
        {
            if (value.equals(curr.item))              {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public void add(Anything value)
  //method that adds a new value to the end of the list
    //COMPLETE
    {      
        
       Node temp = first;
    while(temp.next!=null){ //finds the end
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    temp.next=new Node(value, null); //assigns new value

}
    
     public void enqueue(Anything info){
        if (this.contains(info)==true) { //if the info is already present
            System.out.println("the stack already contains this value");
            return;
        }
        //if we actually need to add the info
         if (first == null) { //if there is nothing in the stack
        Node temp= first; 
        first = new Node<>(info,temp); 
        first = temp;
        return;
    }
      
        if (first != null) { //if there is already stuff
            Node temp = first;
        while (temp.next == null)
        {   Node newNode= new Node<>(info, temp);
            temp.next = newNode;
}
        return;
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Node` class doesn't have a constructor, so why did you expect `new Node<>(info, temp)` to work? I highly recommend you grab your Java learning guide and (re)read the section about object creation and constructors, or to search the web for a better guide!!

Answer (score 1):

As @Andreas already pointed out, `Node` needs a constructor.

There are a few other flaws in your Code:

**Use Generics**

With your Code, you can only store Objects of the class `Anything`, what strongly limits its reusability. Use a generic instead and you can reuse this class for many more purposes.

**Linked List**

I suggest, you use the paradigm of a double-linked-list. That way you do not need to find the last `Node` to add something to the Stack. `Node` now has a pointer to its previous and next element.

**Use the `last` Object**

You have the object `last` but never use it. To find out, whether the current object is the last one you compare the value to `null`. This has the effect, that storing a `null` value will break your List. Instead compare to the Object `last`, this object is unique and guarantees you, that you are at the end of the list. Both `first` and `last` are `Node`s that do not contain a value and are simply used to mark the start/end of your List.

**Adding elements**

Using the changes above, the code in the Method `enqueue(T value)` becomes significantly simpler: You just check whether `contains(value)` and decide whether you add the value to the List or not.

All these changes applied result in following code:

```
public class MyStack<T extends Object> {
    private Node first, last;
    
    public MyStack() {
        first = new Node(null, null, null);
        last = new Node(null, null, first);
        first.next = last;
    }

    private class Node {
        T item;
        Node next;
        Node previous;
        
        public Node(T item, Node next, Node previous) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(T value) {
        for (Node curr = first.next; curr != last; curr = curr.next) {
            if (value.equals(curr.item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * method that adds a new value to the end of the list
     */
    public void add(T value)
    {
        Node secondLast = last.previous;
        Node added = new Node(value, last, secondLast);
        secondLast.next = added;
        last.previous = added;
    }

    /**
     * only adds value if it is not already contained by the Stack
     */
    public void enqueue(T value) {
        if (this.contains(value) == true) { // if the info is already present
            System.out.println("the stack already contains this value");
        }
        else {
            add(value);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack<String> test = new MyStack<>();
        test.add("foo");
        test.add("bar");
        test.add("baz");
        
        System.out.println(test.contains("bar"));
        System.out.println(test.contains("new"));
        
        test.enqueue("baz");
        test.enqueue("MyStack");
    }
}
```

**Naming**

As you may have noticed, in my explanation I called this class a List. This is because it fulfills more of the characteristics of a List. A Stack usually only provides the methods `push` to put something at the top of the Stack and `pop` to remove and return the topmost Object. Optionally `peek` can return the topmost Object, without removing it from the Stack.

Also consider renaming the method `enqueue`: enqueue is used in Queues (obviously) and Queues do not forbid to add two equal Objects. So the name is misleading. I would call this method something like `addIfNotContaining`.

In my Opinion you should name this class to be a List and add a method `get(int i)` to get a specific element at a position. Naturally adding some other methods like `size` ect. to comply with a standard List. But I assume you already had, but did not post them because they are not related to your problem.

**Multithreading**

This Class is far from threadsave. But I let you figure out yourself how to make it threadsave if needed.